# Replace 'if' with 'should' in sentences with 'can'

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

I know I can replace 'if' with 'should' in a condition for tone or style. What if the sentence has 'can', does it become 'could'?

E.g. original sentence

> If you can read this, bring me coffee.

Is it correct to say

> Could you read this, bring me coffee.

Or is it my only option to say

> Should you be able to read this, bring me coffee.

Are there other ways to express the same thing (with 'should')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to ask for a favor without using **if** by putting modal **could** in initial position:

> Could you see your way to do that for us, it would be an immense
>   help and we would be very grateful.

That is the semantic equivalent of "If you could see your way to do that for us..."

This construction is old-fashioned and it is rarely used nowadays. I suspect some speakers would think it was rather odd.

Comment: I find it more acceptable in the first or third person, and especially with the adverb "but": _Could he but read it, he would be happy._

Comment: @ColinFine What does 'but' mean here? Is it used to reinforce the hypothetical nature of the phrase?

Comment: **But** there is a synonym for **only**, @NS.X.  *If **only** he could read it.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: Not in my book. "If only he could read it" is expressing a fervent wish. "If he could but read it" is reinforcing the hypothetical nature, as NS X said, but does not carry an emotional charge.

Comment: @Colin Fine:  **if only** can  express  fervent wish, as you say, but that is not its only meaning; it can express a less emotional *irrealis* too.  And **if he could but...**  can have the same emotional charge as **if only he**.